# Why app.use(...) can't be declared in an async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, express-session

I'm trying to set up a node.js server using the express framework and implement sessions.

This works :

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');

var server = express();
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

server.use(session({secret: 'mySuperSecretKey'}));

server.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('listening...');
});

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.session.aSessionEntry = 'value';
    res.send('Your session entry is' + req.session.aSessionEntry);
});
```

However, when I declare the server.use(session(...)) inside an async function, it is ignored - the session handling doesn't work anymore.

Here :

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');

var server = express();
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.get("sessionSecret", function(err, reply) {
    server.use(session({secret: reply.toString()}));
};

server.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('listening...');
});

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    req.session.aSessionEntry = 'value';
    res.send('Your session entry is' + req.session.aSessionEntry);
});
```

Why isn't it possible to do this ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think that if you put `server.listen` inside your async function's callback, it should work

Comment: Most probably because `use` is a setup function to add in middleware. By the time you call `listen`, express uses what's been configured. But putting it in an async operation's callback means `listen` gets called first, without the session setup.

Comment: See http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use. Order of definition is important, there could be an issue with `.get` being registered first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware must be installed before specific route handlers.  If you look in the Express code for `app.use()` and `app.get()`, they both add handlers into the internal router stack and those handlers are search in the order they were added, regardless of whether they were middleware handlers or endpoint handlers.  So, if you put your endpoint handlers first before the middleware handlers, then the middleware may not get called and certainly won't get called before the endpoint (thus likely defeating its purpose).

If you want to install your middleware async, then you need to install all the route handlers AFTER that async middleware is installed.

Comment: I tried it and it works. And now I understand how the route handlers and the middleware work. Thank you !